# Sorting rows based on variable group in a data frame

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I've got a dataframe that looks like this -

```
df=data.frame(Code=c('Q1','Q1','Q1','Q1','Q2','Q2','Q2','Q2','Q3','Q3','Q3','Q3'),
          Fiscal_Year=c('FY18','FY16','FY17','FY15','FY15','FY18','FY17','FY16','FY15','FY16','FY17','FY18'),
          Score=c(0.23,0.25,0.32,0.41,0.61,0.54,0.45,0.51,0.78,0.79,0.81,0.84))
```

My objective is to group by question `Code` (which is already the case in the dataframe), and then for each group, sort rows in increasing order of `Fiscal_Year`.

The fiscal years are FY15 (Fiscal Year 2015), FY16 (Fiscal Year 2016), FY17 (Fiscal Year 2017), & FY18 (Fiscal Year 2018).

> So the order of levels are FY15 < FY16 < FY17 < FY18.

In order to define the levels in R, I did the following -

```
#Convert column to factor
df$Fiscal_Year=as.factor(df$Fiscal_Year)
#Define order of levels
levels(df$Fiscal_Year)=c("FY15","FY16","FY17","FY18")
```

Next, I wish to group by `Code` and then **sort in increasing order** of `Fiscal_Year` **within each group**.

So for example, for the question group `Q2`, I'd like the rows to be sorted in increasing order of Fiscal Year (FY15,FY16,FY17,FY18). And the same for the other question groups.

**My Attempt**

Using the dplyr package, I tried to do this

```
library(dplyr)

df=sat %>%
group_by(CTQ_QUEST_CODE,FY) %>%
arrange(CTQ_QUEST_CODE,desc(FY))
```

However I do not get the result I'm looking for.

Any inputs on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `.by_group = TRUE` to `arrange()`:

```
df %>%
        group_by(Code) %>%
        arrange(Fiscal_Year, .by_group = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can `arrange` by `Code` and the number part in `Fiscal_Year`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df %>%
    arrange(Code, parse_number(Fiscal_Year))

#   Code Fiscal_Year Score
#1    Q1        FY15  0.41
#2    Q1        FY16  0.25
#3    Q1        FY17  0.32
#4    Q1        FY18  0.23
#5    Q2        FY15  0.61
#6    Q2        FY16  0.51
#7    Q2        FY17  0.45
#8    Q2        FY18  0.54
#9    Q3        FY15  0.78
#10   Q3        FY16  0.79
#11   Q3        FY17  0.81
#12   Q3        FY18  0.84
```

Answer (score 1):

From Base R `order`

```
df[order(df$Code,df$Fiscal_Year),]
   Code Fiscal_Year Score
4    Q1        FY15  0.41
2    Q1        FY16  0.25
3    Q1        FY17  0.32
1    Q1        FY18  0.23
5    Q2        FY15  0.61
8    Q2        FY16  0.51
7    Q2        FY17  0.45
6    Q2        FY18  0.54
9    Q3        FY15  0.78
10   Q3        FY16  0.79
11   Q3        FY17  0.81
12   Q3        FY18  0.84
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just get rid of the `desc()` from the `arrange()` statement?

```
> df %>%
+ group_by(Code,Fiscal_Year) %>%
+ arrange(Code,Fiscal_Year)

# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   Code, Fiscal_Year [12]

   Code  Fiscal_Year Score
   <fct> <fct>       <dbl>
 1 Q1    FY15         0.41
 2 Q1    FY16         0.25
 3 Q1    FY17         0.32
 4 Q1    FY18         0.23
 5 Q2    FY15         0.61
 6 Q2    FY16         0.51
 7 Q2    FY17         0.45
 8 Q2    FY18         0.54
 9 Q3    FY15         0.78
10 Q3    FY16         0.79
11 Q3    FY17         0.81
12 Q3    FY18         0.84

> df %>% arrange(Code, Fiscal_Year)

   Code Fiscal_Year Score
1    Q1        FY15  0.41
2    Q1        FY16  0.25
3    Q1        FY17  0.32
4    Q1        FY18  0.23
5    Q2        FY15  0.61
6    Q2        FY16  0.51
7    Q2        FY17  0.45
8    Q2        FY18  0.54
9    Q3        FY15  0.78
10   Q3        FY16  0.79
11   Q3        FY17  0.81
12   Q3        FY18  0.84
```